# How do you specify the concrete implementation to be used for a class through Android Resources or Manifest

Tags: android

Suppose I have a Android Application which can have different navigational capabilities based on the concrete class attached to the application. How to specify the concrete class. Android Resources (R.java) doesnt talk anything about Objects. I do agree that I can have classname as a String attribute and then instantiate through Reflection.. but I am not in favor of that solution.

Which other way I can attach a concrete implementation to the Android Application so that depending on this object, the application can behave differently in different builds.

Comment: What do you mean by navigational capabilities?

Comment: Lets assume that the App can have different navigation in Android Device#1 vs that in Android Device#2. I am looking for something on how to tie the Concrete Factory to be tied to the Android Application when the Application is built into a APK.

Answer (score 0):

Consider declaring an interface and have all of the concrete classes implement the interface as plug ins. Then you can either hand code a single line of code such as

```
Model model= new Model(new MyConcreteClassSpec());
```

where MyConcreteClassSpec implements IMyModelSpec

Or you can pass an integer value and return a concrete class using a class factory as in:

```
Model getInstanceModel(int i);
```

Using an int instead of a enum makes the class factory extensible in the future.

Comment: I am looking forward to how we can tie the concrete factory into the Application without the Application not even knowing about the existence of the Factory. (Like what we do about Swing L&F). getInstanceModel(int) will make the application know about the existence of the concrete class during compilation time itself.

Comment: @jVenki  The problem is that I do not fully understand your requirements and I am more fully qualified in C#. If you are trying to load a class at runtime based on device type, then I would think you could discover the type and call getInstanceModel(DEVICE_TYPE). Of course you would need to know all of the device types and Models at compile time. If you want to load an unknown class at runtime, consider programming to an interface and loading the class at runtime using dynamic discovery and reflection.